# How to get stack backtrace from Rust addon to Electron app

Tags: rust, electron, neon-bindings

I am using neon to create a Rust addon to an Electron app.  It's basically working, but every time there's a crash I get an error message like "attempt to divide by zero" but no location, and as the code base grows it gets increasingly onerous to figure out where the problem is.

I tried changing the build script from

```
electron-build-env neon build my_addon --release
```

to

```
electron-build-env neon build my_addon
```

and setting the usual env var

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 my_app
```

but got no backtrace.  I couldn't find this written up anywhere, but surely it is possible.  Can anyone show me how to do this?

UPDATE:  It occurs to me that when you build in debug mode, the binary goes into a different directory -- target/debug vs. target/release -- and I haven't done anything to account for that (unless "neon" vs "neon --release" does it).  Grepping didn't turn up the text "target/release" anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't getting an answer here, so I looked around and found that there is a Neon Community on Slack and asked the question there.  There kjv (K. J. Valencik, who I think is the author of neon-bindings and neon-serde) said that Neon attempts to turn panics into Javascript exceptions, sending nothing to stderr.  It isn't yet clear to me whether such a Javascript exception would contain the Rust backtrace if the add-on were compiled in debug mode; there is no backtrace with release mode.  To be continued....